# How to change how strict MySQL throws errors?

Tags: mysql

a while ago I remember coming accross a thread on how to make it so MySQL isn't so strict when it throws errors, for example when I run a C# program, and it uses MySQL; sometimes when it tries to post data, or access it, MySQL will throw stupid errors such as:

```
Field xxx doesn't have a default value
```

I basically recall it being how strict MySQL error reporting is, or something like that.. But I'm not sure if this is correct. I have a few people on forums who've been having the same errors, but don't know that there's a way to stop MySQL from being so strict on error reporting.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: why don't you fix the errors (it's actually a warning) instead of preventing the errors being thrown ?

Comment: Some programs are coded in different versions of MySQL, which means if I use a program in a older version of MySQL compared to a newer one, it will throw pointless errors and stop the execution of my application.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors as of now, but they're just errors like what I posted in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Add strict mode for `sql_mode` like below.

```
set sql_mode='strict';
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for, sorry.

Comment: you want the opposite of that. look up the mysql docs for sql_mode values\

Answer (score 0):

***How to change how strict MySQL throws errors?***

> *if have you created insert trigger on same table which copy same record into another same table . once you have **removed trigger** my application runs as usual . mysql team should look into the trigger creation for the error arises of it.*

***https://www.farbeyondcode.com/Solution-for-MariaDB-Field--xxx--doesn-t-have-a-default-value-5-2720.html***

***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict***

***http://www.mavengineering.com/blog/2012/12/06/turning-on-strict-mode-for-mysql-installed-with-homebrew/***